# About weakly associated primes

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative ring, and $M$ an $A$-module. A prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}\subset A$ is said to be *weakly associated* to $M$ if it is minimal over some $\operatorname{ann}m$, where $m\in M$. I came across a statement that says,
$$\operatorname{WeakAss}_{A}S^{-1}M=\operatorname{WeakAss}_{S^{-1}A}S^{-1}M.$$
(Source: Lemma 10.63.14 in http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0546)

It is a well known result for ordinary associated primes ($\operatorname{Ass}_{A}S^{-1}M=\operatorname{Ass}_{S^{-1}A}S^{-1}M$), but for weakly associated primes, I suspect it should be
$$\operatorname{WeakAss}_{A}S^{-1}M\cap\operatorname{Spec}S^{-1}A=\operatorname{WeakAss}_{S^{-1}A}S^{-1}M.$$
Did I discover a typo, or am I missing something? (Surely I'm more likely to make a mistake than Columbia University?) Is every weakly associated prime of $S^{-1}M$ as an $A$-module necessarily disjoint from $S$ for some reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\p}{\mathfrak{p}}$$\DeclareMathOperator{\ann}{\operatorname{ann}}$Let $\p \in \operatorname{WeakAss}_A S^{-1}M$ be minimal over $\ann_A(\frac{m}{1})$. Since annihilators localize (Lemma), $\ann_A(\frac{m}{1}) = (\ann_A(m))^{ec}$, where extension/contraction are with respect to $A \to S^{-1}A$. Now suppose $s \in \p \cap S$. Then by assumption, $s$ is nilpotent in $(A/\ann_A(m)^{ec})_{\p}$, so $s^nx \in \ann_A(m)^{ec}$ for some $x \in A \setminus \p$, so $\frac{s^nx}{1} \in \ann_A(m)^{ece} = \ann_A(m)^e$. Thus $x \in (\ann_{A}(m))^{ec} \subseteq \p$, contradiction.

**Lemma:** $\ann_{S^{-1}A}(\frac{m}{1}) = S^{-1}(\ann_A(m)) \; (= \ann_A(m)^e)$ for any $m \in M$.

Comment: Thanks! I think your proof can be streamlined a bit by stating a lemma: Let $\tau:A\to S^{-1}A$ be the localization, and $I\subset A$ a contracted ideal with respect to $\tau$. If $sa\in I$, where $s\in S$, then $a\in I$.

Comment: zcn: The ideal $I$ in my comment above is any contracted ideal, not necessarily $\operatorname{ann}_A(m/1)$.

Comment: @ashpool: I agree with your lemma - the last line of my argument is (more or less) its proof

Answer (score 3):

I think zcn's answer is great, but here's a minor modification that avoids using extensions/contractions. (It doesn't really avoid using them, just hides that we're using them but it is in any case slightly more direct and easier for me to understand.) Moreover, both zcn's answer and mine only prove one containment, but the other is not so hard so I'll leave it out. The argument can be found in my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1155567/exercise-5-5-f-on-ravi-vakils-notes-related-to-associated-points), if you're willing to wade through some geometric content.

Suppose $\mathfrak{p} \in \operatorname{WeakAss}_{A}(S^{-1}M)$, say $\mathfrak{p}$ is minimal over $\operatorname{Ann}_A(\frac{m}{s})$. Now suppose $t \in \mathfrak{p}\cap S$. Then since $\mathfrak{p}_\mathfrak{p}$ is the unique minimal prime lying over $\operatorname{Ann}_A(\frac{m}{s})_{\mathfrak{p}}$ in $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$, $t$ is nilpotent in $A_{\mathfrak{p}}/\operatorname{Ann}_A(\frac{m}{s})_{\mathfrak{p}}\cong (A/\operatorname{Ann}_A(\frac{m}{s}))_{\mathfrak{p}}$, that is to say there exists some $x \in A\setminus \mathfrak{p}$ with $t^nx \in \operatorname{Ann}_A(\frac{m}{s})$. But then $x \in \operatorname{Ann}_A(\frac{m}{s}) \subset \mathfrak{p}$, a contradiction.

There are a few ways to see that $x$ annihilates $\frac{m}{s}$ if $t^nx$ does, if you don't see it immediately (I didn't!). One is to actually write down from definitions what it means for an element of $A$ to annihilate an element of $S^{-1}M$ and observe that for $a \in A, s \in S$, $a$ annihilates an element iff $sa$ does, or you can just write $\frac{m}{s} = \frac{t^nm}{t^ns}$ and then use that $x(\frac{m}{s}) = x\frac{t^nm}{t^ns}= \frac{xt^n}{s}\frac{1}{t^n} = 0$. The first method is perhaps more enlightening, and can be thought of as being a consequence of the fact that $s$ "acts as a unit on $M$".

Comment: Excepting the useless use of a denominator like $s$ and a whole paragraph about a trivial remark like $t^nx\cdot\frac ms=0\implies x\cdot \frac ms=0$ (I suppose everyone knows that if $t\in S$ then $t^n$ is invertible in $S^{-1}R$) I really don't think this answer brings something new.

Comment: @user26857 You're certainly welcome to your opinion, I didn't claim to have something new at any rate, just something that avoided extension and contraction. I used $s$ because perhaps someone reading this wouldn't realise that it doesn't matter, which is the same reason I further explained the implication you mention. Since we're not working in $S^{-1}R$ (and that's the whole point of this question), it need not be true that $t^n$ is invertible, even though it acts by an isomorphism on our module. I think there's no harm in explaining that, especially since it's something easy to miss.

Comment: We are not working in $S^{-1}R$ but we are working in $S^{-1}M$ which is an $S^{-1}R$-module, so what I said applies.